# c# webmethod parsing dictionary as parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, webmethod

How to receive data from jquery like : data[q]

I tried using

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string GetListData(Dictionary data)
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

ajax part

```
$("#tmptest").ajaxChosen(
      { type: 'GET',
        url: '/ajax/testing.asmx/GetLocationsDetail',
        dataType: 'json' },
        function (data) 
             {
                var terms = {};
                $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                       terms[i] = val; 
                      });
                return terms;
     });
```

and got http 500 error, really don't know what is the problem causing that error

Thanks for your help

Comment: Share your ajax part as well..

Comment: $("#tmptest").ajaxChosen({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/ajax/testing.asmx/GetLocationsDetail',
                    dataType: 'json'
                },
                  function (data) {
                      var terms = {};
                      $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                          terms[i] = val;
                      });

                      return terms;
                  });